# Select value into the textbox FROM ajax using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the results from the database whether username is available or not . But it is not giving any results i am not getting ajax response this is the html code

```
<form id="user_form">
        <input placeholder="username here" type="text" name="ajax-data" id="ajax-data">
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" Value="Submit">
    </form>
    <span class="php_responce_here"></span>
```

This is the ajax code which i have used

```
     $(document).ready(function()
         {
    $("form#user_form").click(function()
    {
        var textboxvalue = $('input[name=ajax-data]').val();

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: 'second.php',
            data: {ajax-data: textboxvalue},
            success: function(result)
            {
                $(".php_responce_here").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});​
                </script>
```

final code of php where i have used the validation and the query to find whether the username is available in the database or not the problem is that it is not giving any of the result

```
         <?php
error_reporting(0); 
    require "config.php";// configuration file holds the database info

    $user_name = $_POST['ajax-data']; // textbox in the html


    if($user_name)
    {
        $usernamecheck=  mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE username='$user_name'");
        $check=  mysql_fetch_row($usernamecheck);
        if($check[0]==0)
        {
            if($user_name!=""){
                if(strlen($user_name)>25){
                    echo "You have reached the maximum limit";
                }
                else{
                    echo "User name is valid";
                 }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "username is empty";   
            }
        }
        else{
           echo "Username Already Taken";
       }
    }

?>
```

Comment: first of all you should use `mysql_num_rows` instead of `mysql_fetch_row`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be submit event not click:

```
$("form#user_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var textboxvalue = $('input[name=ajax-data]').val();

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: 'second.php',
        data: { "ajax-data": textboxvalue },
        success: function(result) {
            $(".php_responce_here").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

and as @Cyril BOGNOU pointed out;

```
data: { "ajax-data": textboxvalue }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should too add data type to be returned with the parameter if you want to return JSON for example

> dataType: 'JSON',

and Yes I think you should better write

> data: { "ajax-data": textboxvalue }

So the update should be

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("form#user_form").click(function()
    {
    var textboxvalue = $('input[name=ajax-data]').val();

    $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: 'second.php',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {"ajax-data": textboxvalue},
                success: function(result)
                {
                    $(".php_responce_here").html(result.message);
                }
        });
    });
});
```

and return json string from PHP script

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
require "config.php"; // configuration file holds the database info

$user_name = $_POST['ajax-data']; // textbox in the html


if ($user_name) {
    $usernamecheck = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE username='$user_name'");
    $check = mysql_fetch_row($usernamecheck);
    if ($check[0] == 0) {
        if ($user_name != "") {
            if (strlen($user_name) > 25) {
                $message = "You have reached the maximum limit";
            } else {
                $message = "User name is valid";
            }
        } else {
            $message = "username is empty";
        }
    } else {
        $message = "Username Already Taken";
    }
    echo json_encode(["message" => $message]);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty page? Nothing prints out?

```
<?php
  error_reporting(-1);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

  require "config.php";// configuration file holds the database info  

  if(isset($username = $_POST['ajax-data'])){
    if($l = strlen($username) <= 25 && $l > 2){
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'"; // wide open for SQL injections. use mysqli or PDO instead.
      if($rsl = mysql_query($sql) != false){ // ALWAYS verify if your query's ran successfully.
        if(mysql_num_rows($rsl) != 0){
          echo 'Username already exists';
        } else {
          echo 'Username is available';
        }
      } else {
        echo 'Query failed: ' . mysql_error();
      }
    } else {
      echo $l > 25 ? 'Reached limit' : 'Needs to be longer';
    }
  } else {
    echo "post['ajax-data'] not set<\br>";
    print_r($_POST);
  }

?>
```

Then there is your Javascript code that I have questions on. Yet you have a submit button but you want to check if its valid upon change?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#user_form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: "second.php",
      type: "post",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(result){
        $(".php_responce_here").html(result);
      }
    });
  });
});​
```

Comment: any of the code is not working displaying nothing on the screen !!

Comment: Hence, take a look at `error_reporting(0); // disable reporting while developing?` do a `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and  `error_reporting(-1)`

Answer (score 0):

NOTE : `mysql` is deprecated. you should use `mysqli` or `PDO`

There are some mistakes in your code. check the below code. it should work.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").submit(function (event) {
            var textboxvalue = $("#ajax-data").val();
            $.ajax({
                data: {ajaxdata: textboxvalue},
                type: "POST",
                url: 'second.php',
                success: function (result)
                {
                    $(".php_responce_here").html(result);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can not create variable `ajax-data` with `-`.

PHP

```
$usernamecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user_name'");
$check = mysql_num_rows($usernamecheck);
```

you should use `mysql_num_rows` instead of `mysql_fetch_row`. it will auto calculate the rows.

Check working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/urfusion/pd81dfuo/)